# Iterate through df rows and sum values of two columns separately until condition is met on one of those columns

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, conditional-statements

I am definitely still learning python and have tried countless approaches, but can't figure this one out.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, call them A and B. I need to return a df that will sum the row values of each of these two columns independently until a threshold sum of A exceeds some value, for this example let's say 10. So far I am am trying to use iterrows() and can get segment based on if A >= 10, but can't seem to solve summation of rows until the threshold is met. The resultant df must be exhaustive even if the final A values do not meet the conditional threshold - see final row of desired output.

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[20,16],[10,5],[3,2],[1,1],[12,10],[9,7],[6,6],[5,2]],columns=['A','B'])
    df1
        A   B
    0   20  16
    1   10  5
    2   3   2
    3   1   1
    4   12  10
    5   9   7
    6   6   6
    7   5   2
```

Desired result:

```
        A   B
    0   20  16
    1   10  5
    2   16  13
    3   15  13
    4   5   2
```

Thank you in advance, much time spent, and assistance is much appreciated!!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one that works that's shorter:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[20,16],[10,5],[3,2],[1,1],[12,10],[9,7],[6,6],[5,2]],columns=['A','B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
index = 0
while index < df1.size/2:
    if df1.iloc[index]['A'] >= 10:
        a = df1.iloc[index]['A']
        b = df1.iloc[index]['B']
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[a,b]], columns=['A','B'])
        df2 = df2.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
        index += 1
    else:
        a_sum = 0
        b_sum = 0
        while a_sum < 10 and index < df1.size/2:
            a_sum += df1.iloc[index]['A']
            b_sum += df1.iloc[index]['B']
            index += 1
        if a_sum >= 10:
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[a_sum,b_sum]], columns=['A','B'])
            df2 = df2.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            a = df1.iloc[index-1]['A']
            b = df1.iloc[index-1]['B']
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[a,b]], columns=['A','B'])
            df2 = df2.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

The key is to keep track of where you are in the DataFrame and track the sums. Don't be afraid to use variables.

In Pandas, use iloc to access each row by index. Make sure you don't go out of the DataFrame by checking the size. df.size returns the number of elements, so it will multiply the rows by the columns. This is why I divided the size by the number of columns, to get the actual number of rows.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance in addition to the answer...Both responses worked and after a couple minor "lost in translation" hiccups ( I oversimplified , I'm able to move forward with my work. Thank you so very much again!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Please select one of the answer that best fit to what you were asking by selecting it as the answer to your question...if both work, David's was first and should be marked as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely write long loops for pandas, but I didn't see a way to do this with a pandas method. Try this horrible loop :( :

1. The variable I created `t` is essentially checking the cumulative sums to see if > `n` (which we have set to 10). Then, we decide to use `t`, the cumulative some or `i` the value in the dataframe for any given row (`j` and `u` are just there in parallel with to the same thing for column B).
2. There are a few conditions so some `elif` statements, and there will be different behavior for the last row the way I have set it up, so I had to have some separate logic for that with the last `if` -- otherwise the last value wasn't getting appended:

---

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[20,16],[10,5],[3,2],[1,1],[12,10],[9,7],[6,6],[5,2]],columns=['A','B'])
df1

a,b = [],[]
t,u,count = 0,0,0
n=10
for (i,j) in zip(df1['A'], df1['B']):
    count+=1
    if i < n and t >= n:
        a.append(t)
        b.append(u)
        t = i
        u = j
    elif 0 < t < n:
        t += i
        u += j
    elif i < n and t == 0:
        t += i
        u += j
    else:
        t = 0
        u = 0
        a.append(i)
        b.append(j)
    if count == len(df1['A']):
        if t == i or t == 0:
            a.append(i)
            b.append(j)
        elif t > 0 and t != i:
            t += i
            u += j
            a.append(t)
            b.append(u)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : a, 'B' : b})
df2
```

Comment: @wpy please let me know if this works on your dataframe. If not, give me an example of where it broke.

Comment: Thank you David! I will adapt your solution this morning and get back...thank you again!